# Detect SetWindowsHookExA WH_MOUSE_LL detachment / unhooking

Tags: winapi, hook

I have a little Python script which collects statistics about my keyboard and mouse usage on a Windows machine.

I set it up via `windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, mouse_pointer, win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)`. I write this so that you can see which API I'm using. It could just as well have been a c++ programm.

It works perfectly fine, with one exception: When I use Android Studio to compile an app, my Core i7 with 4 cores maxes out at 100% on all cores, the mouse and the OS in general becomes unresponsive, which is a known issue with Android Studio.

Usually when such a very high CPU load occurs for a couple of seconds (4+) the WH_MOUSE_LL hook gets detached by the OS, as if it's saying *"Nope, we don't have time for you, we're unregistering you"*

I don't blame this on Python, because I also have a sound volume manager called [PowerMixer](http://www.actualsolution.com/power-mixer/) which apparently also registers a mouse hook so that it can track mouse scroll wheel actions on the lower taskbar (explorer.exe Shell_TrayWnd) and this application also looses it's ability to use that mouse hook after compiling.

Also, when I am compiling and constantly scroll the scroll wheel (just for fun) the computer starts to beep, as in a very low level system beep and then the keyboard hooks get unregistered as well.

How can I detect via the Windows API if my hooks got detached / unhooked? I don't require a Python specific answer, just infos on the proper way to use the Win32 API to deal with this.

The **remarks** section of the [SetWindowsHookEx documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the
>   next hook. However, on Windows 7 and later, the hook is silently
>   removed without being called. There is no way for the application to
>   know whether the hook is removed.

Am I out of luck here?

**Update**: A couple of weeks later, I just want to inform that Hans Passan's suggestion is working very well. I recommend this. While 10.000 ms seems a bit high, I've set it to this value and have no negative effects. This is the way to go to solve the issue system wide within a couple of minutes.

Comment: Just increase the timeout, it is registry setting.  Add the LowLevelHooksTimeout value, a  DWORD, to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop key.  Set it to 10000 to double the timeout.

Comment: *"I don't blame this on Python, because I also have [another program, that exhibits the same behavior, under the same conditions, using the same library]"*. - That seems fairly inconclusive, and I wouldn't discard anything as the source with that little information. Pull a minidump of both Android Studio as well as your python script when they start failing, and analyze them later. This may reveal interesting information.

Comment: @IInspectable you may be right. But debugging this issue that way is not worth the time and effort to me. It was a quick decision made due to the fact that this sound manager I'm mentioning also has the same problem and that one is definitely not written in Python.

Comment: I don't suppose you ever found out what was causing your beep? I'm doing something similar and get the low level beep when using SetWindowsHooksEX and scrolling and am trying to resolve it.

Comment: @Sidney Nope, I have not. Hans Passant's registry tweak solved the issue for me. I still do get the beeps while compiling, but the hooks are not getting removed, I can live with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I detect via the Windows API if my hooks got detached / unhooked?

There is no *direct* way to do it, and your own question quoted the MSDN documentation that backs it up:

> If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the next hook. However, on Windows 7 and later, **the hook is silently removed without being called. There is no way for the application to know whether the hook is removed**.

However, an *indirect* way might be to have your hook keep track of the last time it is called, and then your main app/script can call [`GetLastInputInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302.aspx) periodically and compare that time to your tracked time.  If the difference is a significant margin higher than the hook timeout that is stored in the Registry (see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx)), it is probably a good bet that your hook may be gone.

The following MSDN blog explains the details of the hook timeout:

[Global hooks getting lost on Windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2010/10/14/global-hooks-getting-lost-on-windows-7/)

But, most importantly, it states:

> My recommendation is that **low level hooks should be avoided whenever possible**. If you are monitoring keystrokes (and not trying to block them), you can get the keyboard input via Raw Input. This is lighter weight than hooks, won’t affect other apps’ responsiveness, and **won’t be turned off if the app isn’t responsive**.

Which is the same as Microsoft's own recommendation in the [`LowLevelMouseProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx) and [`LowLevelKeyboardProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) documentations:

> If the application must use low level hooks, it should run the hooks on a dedicated thread that passes the work off to a worker thread and then immediately returns. **In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead**. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can. For more information on raw input, see [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I incremented the timeout as Hans Passant commented, and apparently that is working. If the problem still shows up I'll definitely do the `GetLastInputInfo()` thing, as I'm also running a timer that gets called every 15 seconds which analyzes the gathered data and stores into a database. That place would be the perfect spot to include that functionality. Also thanks for the links and additional info, I might switch to the Raw Input thing when I find some time for it. A really nice answer.

Comment: BTW an odd thing is that AutoHotkey is not affected by this.

Comment: AutoHotKey is open-source, feel free to [view its source code](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L) to see how it handles this.